# What is exactly Triangular bottom database in algorithm design course?

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

For algorithm design course, the teacher gave a question, but i don't understand it at all, specially the triangular bottom database which i searched about it but couldn't find any result. However the question is as follow:

In the facing database, calculate the execution order in cpu-based load mode and memory-based load mode.

[image]

Write pseudocode and execution order calculations.

Can you please help me with this question? Even a hint to at least I understand the question!

I'm just trying to understand it.

Thanks a lot community.

Comment: I think to answer this, we need more information provided by your database in algorithm design course, so maybe a fellow student who also takes the course can more likely help.

Comment: If you have doubts, ask your teacher. I am sure he/she will explain the problem statement to you.

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes but the problem is that here in my country is Noruz which is a ceremony and schools and universities are closed about 15 days (its our holidays like Christmas our new year). also i dont have any access to him ( like a phone number or an email). this is not homework but want to understand it.